# How to determine electric field strength without Gauss's Law

Tags: electrostatics

For objects which do not subscribe to Gauss's Law, I don't understand how one would determine the electric field strength. I know that the equation $E=k\int \frac{\mathrm{d}q}{r^2}$ can be used to find the electric field over infinitely long lines of charges, but I'm not sure how to use it. In the case of dq, what role does this infinitesimally small charge play in the equation? Sorry not to have specifics, however, I just don't have any idea how to use this equation.

Comment: All objects "subscribe" to Gauss' Law. It's just that they don't necessarily have the level of symmetry that makes the Law an appealing way to compute the fields associated with them.

Comment: Ok, so if the shape of an object makes Gauss' Law overly complicated, what can you do to find the electric field strength without overly complicating things?

Comment: The integral you exhibit is one special case of applying the general strategy: you integrate the field due to point charges over the charge distribution. If you don't understand integrals imagine slicing the charge distribution is very many very small boxes and then treating the total charge in each box as a point charge. Just sum their contributions up. But to actually do the work that way you want calculus.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I need to review calculus. I think that's where I'm getting hung up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the formula is $$\vec{E}(P)=k\int \frac{dq}{r^2}\hat{r}.$$

To use it pick a point $P$, and then break your charge into many pieces, each of which have a total charge $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,\dots, Q_n$, and a general location $R_1,R_2,R_3,\dots, R_n$.  Then $r$ for that little piece is the distance between $P$ and $R_i$ and $\hat{r}$ for that little piece is the unit vector in the direction from $R_i$ to $P$ and $dq$ for that little piece is $Q_i$, the charge of the piece.

So the electric field due to that little piece of charge is $k\frac{dq}{r^2}\hat{r}$, that's what you add up (like a vector) to get the field due to everything.

As an example you could have a ring of charge $Q$ distributed at the circle $(a\cos(\theta),a\sin(\theta),0)$ and $P$ could be the point $(0,0,z)$, then if we break it into little pieces each with a small angle $d\theta$, then each has charge $dq=\frac{Q}{2\pi a}(ad\theta)$ and has $r=\sqrt{a^2\cos^2(\theta)+a^2\sin^2(\theta)+z^2}=\sqrt{a^2+z^2}$.  And $\hat{r}=\frac{(-a\cos(\theta),-a\sin(\theta),z)}{r}$, so

$$\vec{E}(P)=k\int \frac{dq}{r^2}\hat{r}=k\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \frac{Qd\theta/2\pi}{a^2+z^2}\left(\frac{(-a\cos(\theta),-a\sin(\theta),z)}{\sqrt{a^2+z^2}})\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the in depth response. I'll admit, I get a bit lost with all of the angles, but I'll try to sort through it. Why is the z coordinate left as z and not 0? Or rather, why are x and y specifically 0?

Comment: @sevenofspades That's the point I chose, it makes the integral particularly easy since $a$ and $z$ don't depend on $\theta$ and the other integrals are quite easy.  After you do this problem you could try to do a disk by doing a series of rings.  You could pick any other point, but then the integral is harder to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

That integral is how you do it. At an arbitrary point $\vec{x}$, the total $\vec{E}(\vec{x})$ is the sum of all the very small bits of field $\vec{dE}$ created by each little tiny bit dq of charge. You have to add them all up, as vectors. (The integrand should really be $\frac{\vec{r}dq}{r^3}$). The dq inside the integral is each little bit of charge, and $\vec{r}$ inside the integral is the vector from that little bit of charge to the point $\vec{x}$.

Try to draw a picture of the problem and write dq and r in a general way. You'll be splitting up your charge density into tiny pieces. dq is the amount of charge in each piece and will depend on the charge density, while r will depend on the geometry.